# Knockout custom validation ajax issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to validate whether or not a zip code entered into a form field is valid for a state chosen from a dropdown in the preceeding field. I have all the data in a table and am able to confirm using an ajax call. My code below allows me to make the ajax call an return true/false, but I am not sure how to trigger the validation based off the return value. Does anyone have an idea?

**Custom Validation:**

```
ko.validation.rules["isValidZipCode"] =
    {
        getValue: function (o) {
            return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
        },
        validator: function (val, fields) {
            var self = this;
            var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(fields, function (field) {
                var val = self.getValue(field);

                if (val === undefined || val === null) 
                    return "";                
                return true;
            });

            var ajaxData = { state: anyOne, zipCode: val }
            $.ajax({
                url: $("a#ValidateZipByState").attr("href"),
                type: "POST",
                data: ajaxData,
                success: function (isValid) {
                    if (isValid) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: handleSubmitError
            });

            return;
        },
        message: "Invalid zip code for this state"
    };
```

**ViewModel:**

```
self.State = ko.observable(model.State).extend({ required: true });
self.ZipCode = ko.observable(model.ZipCode).extend({ required: true, pattern: /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/g, isValidZipCode: [self.State, self.ZipCode] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the async flag on your validation definition, and then you can return a result to the callback parameter. [Reference](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Async-Rules)

```
ko.validation.rules["isValidZipCode"] =
{
    async: true,
    getValue: function (o) {
        return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val, fields, callback) {
        var self = this;
        var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(fields, function (field) {
            var val = self.getValue(field);

            if (val === undefined || val === null) 
                return "";                
            return true;
        });

        var ajaxData = { state: anyOne, zipCode: val }
        $.ajax({
            url: $("a#ValidateZipByState").attr("href"),
            type: "POST",
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function (isValid) {
                callback(isValid);
            },
            error: handleSubmitError
        });

        return;
    },
    message: "Invalid zip code for this state"
};
```

Comment: Jason to the rescue again! Thanks a lot bud. I sat on this all day and could not figure it out. I just read the documentation. If you don't mind can you explain what the async: true and callback are doing under the hood? Seems like some KO sourcery to me :)

Comment: That all -is- sorcery as far as I know. knockout-validation is open source so if you're really curious you can look at their source code but I haven't looked under that rock myself.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an async validation. You need to handle the 3rd argument to `validator`:

```
   validator: function (val, fields, callback) {
        var self = this;
        var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(fields, function (field) {
            var val = self.getValue(field);

            if (val === undefined || val === null) 
                return "";                
            return true;
        });

        var ajaxData = { state: anyOne, zipCode: val }
        $.ajax({
            url: $("a#ValidateZipByState").attr("href"),
            type: "POST",
            data: ajaxData,
            success: function (isValid) {
                if (isValid) {
                    callback(true); // HERE
                } else {
                    callback(false); // HERE
                }
            },
            error: handleSubmitError
        });

        return;
    },
```

Comment: Thank you as well Daniel. Really appreciate it!